# Not able to start mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to run a mysql docker container using following command.

```
docker run -d --name mysql156 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSSWORD=mysqlpwd mysql:5.6
```

I am getting the following error.

```
sshil-414HTD6:python sshil$ docker logs -f fc749f29af45
2020-08-03 07:06:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-03 07:06:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-08-03 07:06:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-03 07:06:36+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Comment: You have a typo in `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSSWORD`. Remove the excess `S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, change `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSSWORD` to `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.